# Monte Carlo Optimization with CUDA

Tags: optimization, cuda, gpu, montecarlo

I am dealing with some slowness issues regarding my Monte Carlo simulation that I have developed in CUDA. I have observed very poor performances with my GTX 680 (compute capability 3.0) and I don’t know what is wrong in my way of implementing a Monte Carlo simulation. I tried to ‘unroll’ my loop by doing several paths within my main loop without observing any significant improvements.

I have defined my kernel as following:
       SimulationVolInterp = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('sh_cuda_MC.ptx', 'sh_cuda_MC.cu', 'MCSharedMemory'); 
     SimulationVolInterp.ThreadBlockSize = 2^9;
     SimulationVolInterp.GridSize = 2^5;

Here is my kernel function :

```
__global__ void MC(double* vol_int, double* matrice,const double* randomWalk, int nbreSimulation, int nPaths, double S0, double strike, double T, double drift,  const double* strikes_vec, const double* volatility_mat, int l_strikes_vec) {

    //double mydt = (index - nbreSimulation)/nbreSimulation*dt + dt;
    double dt = T/nPaths;
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x; 
   // unsigned int stride = blockDim.x*gridDim.x;
    unsigned int index = tid;   
    int workingCol = 0; 
    unsigned int previousMove;  
    if (index < nbreSimulation) {
        matrice[index] = S0;  
        for (workingCol=1; workingCol< nPaths; workingCol++) {
            previousMove = index; 
            index += nbreSimulation;
            vol_int[index] = 0.25;
            matrice[index] = matrice[previousMove]*exp((drift - vol_int[index] *vol_int[index] *0.5)*dt + randomWalk[index]*vol_int[index] *sqrt(dt));
        }
   }
}
```

For example,  2^12 simulations x 2^11 steps takes 7 sec, it is quite huge right?!
My classic Monte Carlo on Matlab takes less than one sec…

Could someone help me on this point?

Many thanks

Comment: Can't you just initialize `vol_int` to `0.25` (and not even using an array)? I think it might have a better result.

Comment: Also this way of computing is highly dependent on the previous steps, so try to think about a trade-off here, if you are splitting your calculations in big pieces, you are sacrificing your performance since GPU clock is a lot less than the CPU clock. You have to have a massively parallel algorithm and your instructions should be simple, I don't think assigning 2^11 steps to a single thread is a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Actually, I have simplied my code (constant volatility) but I compute a new volatility at each step. Actually I dont really know how to proceed to split the job per thread. In my opinion, the 2^11 steps have to be performed by one single thread in order to avoid concurrent access right? All the examples I have seen about Monte Carlo simulation in CUDA do the same thing : A thread compute all the steps for one simulation.

Comment: Yes your code is highly dependent on its previous steps, I don't see any way to split it further either, but imagine that a single thread has to do 2^11 steps! of course a CPU can do this faster, but also there are 2^12 of them which in this case can run concurrently, apparently for your hardware at least, this trade-off doesn't add up.

Comment: That's annoying :/ I dont really know how to proceed. Even on 2^6 steps, my program is slower than the CPU code (2^7 threads). I dont see what is wrong in my algorithm/ implementation. I should be able to beat the CPU. :/

Comment: Try this: I think you can calculate `exp((drift - vol_int[index] *vol_int[index] *0.5)*dt + randomWalk[index]*vol_int[index] *sqrt(dt))` outside the `for` statement , of course replacing `vol_int` with your updated constant equivalent.

Comment: Also try to use shared memory for `matrice` and call for a `__syncthreads()` at the end of the `for` statement. Be careful that it is accessible only among threads within a single block.

Comment: And a question: what is the value of `nbreSimulation`?

Comment: Thank you for your help Soroosh Bateni. Actually I have already written a device function which compute the exponential expression. It did not change the performance in a signficant way. I am going to try the shared memory method and I will keep you updated. nbreSimulation is the number of simulation that I have defined in my matlab code. My ideal range for this number is from 2^10 to 2^21 .

Comment: if it is possible, define `nbreSimulation` as threadsperblock * blockspergrid, (if you want to use shared memory then threadsperblock it is).

Comment: Actually this is what I am doing in my matlab code :      'myThreadBlockSize = 2^7;
 myGridSize = 2^5;
 
nbreSimulation = myThreadBlockSize*myGridSize;                   spmd SimulationVolInterp = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('sh_cuda_MC.ptx', 'sh_cuda_MC.cu', 'MCSharedMemory'); SimulationVolInterp.ThreadBlockSize = myThreadBlockSize; SimulationVolInterp.GridSize = myGridSize; [volInterp,res] = feval(SimulationVolInterp,matVol,simu_cuda, r_walk_cuda, nbreSimulation,nPaths,S0,strike,T,drift,vec_Strike_cuda, vec_vol_cuda,N1); resultat = gather(res); resultat1 = gather(volInterp); end'

Comment: I see, you are using gpuMatlab, firstly, `gather()` takes a long time itself, where are your `tic` and `toc` located? try moving the `gather ()`outside them and see how enhanced your calculations are. P.S. you can't use the current `nbreSimulation` and shared memory together.

Comment: I have cleaned up my code just to show you the most important thing. Actually gather() is needed to use my results into Matlab, then if I want to check my performance issues, I will have to do it anyway..

Comment: can you try calculating the steps only within a single block? for example assigning it `2^10` then you can use the shared memory.

Comment: You mean using just one block :  'myThreadBlockSize = 1; myGridSize = 2^10 ? This is not possible because my GPU card is limited to [1024, 1024, 64] for the threadBlockSize and the product should be less than 1024. Do you know how I can a define shared memory with a matlab code? In C, it is easy to define a shared variables, but in CUDA-Matlab, I dont know how to return this shared table in my kernel (since it is not a parameter). Many thanks for the time you have taken to help me on this issue.

Comment: You are very welcome, you can use `C` to write your code and then output the ptx file with `--keep`, you don't need to use this in your MATLAB code, it just enhances the internal speed of your function.Also you can use a single block here, you have 2^10 of X and 2^10 of Y, let alone the 2^6 of  Z. By combining these you can use a single block for each simulation. The for loop iterates 2^11 times and you can assign 2^12 as number of threads per block, resulting in shared memory being accessible among all threads.

Answer (score 2):

The  performance of double precision arithmetic on the GTX 680 is NOT  that great.  I recall at GTC 2012 a Nvidia engineer advised me that the GTX 680 has a lot less double precision FPU's that single precision  FPU's. The card was optimized for gaming not compute.

This bog post http://blog.accelereyes.com/blog/2012/04/26/benchmarking-kepler-gtx-680/
confirms the anecdotal evidence.  Try the new GTX Titan card or try the Monte Carlo simulation in single precision ( I suspect neither of these options are very satisfactory for you).

Answer (score 2):

replace double to float. Double good work, only cuda 3.5